# QUnit returns error in strict mode

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

I'm trying to create a (pure) constructor function and a QUnit test for it:

```
//app.js
function myFunc(param1, param2) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  return this;

}

//test.js
QUnit.test("should return a string and a number", function(assert) {

  assert.ok(myFunc("some-string", 4545435234), "a string and a number were returned");

});
```

The code runs and passes my test until I add `"use strict"` to `app.js`. Then QUnit displays the following fail message:

```
1. Died on test #1 at http://some/url/:1:1: Cannot set property 'param1' of undefined
Source: TypeError: Cannot set property 'param1' of undefined
```

I can get both the code to work and the test to pass if I return the `myFunc` parameters as an array:

```
function myFunc(param1, param2)) {
    return [param1, param2];
}
```

But that just doesn't seem right. I get that this has something to do with var hoisting but I'm not clear about it.

Thanks in advance.
    ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In strict mode JavaScript functions are not given the default context (`this`), thus you must provide the context. Once way to do this is through the `new` keyword. If you change your assertion to the following I think this will work:

`assert.ok(new myFunc("some-string", 4545435234), "a string and a number were returned");`

Comment: 100% fixed. Love to get help from a fellow Washingtonian...thanks!